# Coldfusion 8 crash

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2, coldfusion

I have a very big problem with coldfusion 8 on Windows server 2008 with IIS7.
They are in production server and sometimes the the site is not available, I have to manually end the jrun.exe process from task manager and then the site is available. I realize that the process jrun.exe has abut 1.3Gb of memory used at the time it crash's. It happens 2-3 times a day, I have looking in the coldfusion logs and I did not found anything strange beside some warnings that some job exceeded the 300 sec of time execution.

I forgot to mention that coldfusion is a 32bit application but the windows is a 64bit, this may be the problem?
I'm not such good in coldfusion, so If someone knows how to troubleshoot please let me know
Thanks!

Comment: Anything useful in the coldfusion or jrun logs?  This usually has to do with an issue with the code being run, but can also be related to database or database driver problems.

Comment: In coldfusion logs files there are just some warnings that some jobs exceeded the 300sec time limit. But jrun logs, where can I find them? In Windows logs I found that sometimes coldfuion is restarting, is this OK?

Comment: here are some of the jrun logs

Answer (score 0):

If you're under heavy load the JRun never has a chance to do a garbage cleanup, read up on http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/coldfusion_performance.html and then check your own server to see if the garbage collection has a chance to run.

Check here: http://gruchalski.com/2011/03/24/coldfusion-9-crashing-try-different-garbage-collection/

And try:

```
<cfset runtime = CreateObject("java", "java.lang.Runtime").getRuntime()>
<cfset runtime.gc()>
```

You may also have a problem with the young generation specifically never having a chance to cleanup, if you are running 32-bit make sure your -Xmn value isn't too high, once again consult the first link.